# Azure Notification Hub - Can we create a tag that simply expires after some time?

Tags: push-notification, azure-notificationhub

We have a requirement to register devices with tags to identify them for notifications. Now, if some devices do not want to receive notifications, we simply add another tag for them. For example, if someone is marked with a tag **"Exercise"**, he will be scheduled for a notification for Exercise - and if this guy already did his exercise before schedule, we simply update his installation in Notification Hub, with another tag **Cancel:Exercise**.

Finally, when sending notification, we use the *tag expression*:
**Exercise && !Cancel:Exercise** to send notifications to all those who haven't done exercise.

Now, the problem is that this is recurring and a user marked with "Cancel:Exercise" must get a notification the next day, immaterial of whether he got the notification previous day or not - and to do that, we need to 'remove' this 'cancel' tag from his installation in Notification Hub.

***Proposed Solution*** The proposed solution is to run a daily scheduler to reset the tags for all the devices.

**But then we wonder, what if we need to do this for 1 - 5 million devices?**

Comment: This is a repetitive question with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34395270/azure-notification-hub-how-to-handle-registration-for-a-million-devices. Have you tried import/export in bulk?

Comment: @MimiXu - Now I am using the installation API to create an installation and doing patch updates for the devices for adding/updating/removing the tags. I suppose bulk registration update might not work in that case. My primary questions is that, is this a correct process to loop through 1 - 5 millioin devices and do a patch update OR there is a better process for the same?

Comment: An update that we are planning on providing an easier way of achieving installation management in the upcoming months, so hopefully it will be much simpler!

Comment: @MimiXu Thanks for that update! I'll be looking forward